# how to send items details in shipment update email templates in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I wanted yo send items details in shipment update email templates in magento 2. please help me how to add items in shipment update email template.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add the shipment item details using the following layout method in your email template.

> {{layout handle="sales_email_order_shipment_items"
> shipment_id=$shipment_id order_id=$order_id}}